# Crosscorrelation between 2 time series with a single output

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

Hello everyone and thank you for reading.

I am trying to find if the Hurst exponent of financial time series and their correlation have some kind of relation between them. Actually there is already known that there is some relation. I was trying to check it for thesis and I found that when I took the "most optimal pairs for pair trading" I could not find any relation. I was calculating the pearson correlation coefficient between them and an algorithm for the generalized Hurst exponent:

```
def genHurstExponent(serie,q=1):
  serie=serie.values if hasattr(serie,'values') else serie
  kmax=int(np.log2(len(serie))-2)
  regx=[]
  regy=[]#Inicializamos las listas
  for k in range(kmax) :
    T=2**k
    mT=np.mean(np.abs(serie[T:]-serie[:-T])**q)
    regx.append(np.log(T))
    regy.append(np.log(mT)) 
  stats.linregress(regx,regy)
  return stats.linregress(regx,regy).slope/q
```

I have tried this algorithm for
synthetic series and it works fine so I think my problem is with the correlation. I am trying cross-correlation but when I use scipy.signal.correlate it return a vector. I am looking for a single value as a return but I am not sure how to implement it and I have not found any clue through the internet.

Do you have any idea of how could I implement it? I am a bloody beginner at programming and I am really really lost.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why [scipy.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) returns a vector is because it is computing the correlation considering shifted versions of the signal. This is very useful if you may have a delay to the effect of one signal to be observed in the other. If you want the best correlation up to time shifts you can do the following

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
y[37:] += x[:-37] # interference of x observed in y
Z = scipy.signal.correlate(x, y)
lag = np.arange(-99, 100);
print(lag[np.argmax(abs(Z))]) # should show you -37
```

When you plot it you should see a peak in the where the effect is observed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
plt.plot(lag, abs(Z))
plt.ylabel('correlation')
plt.xlabel('lag')
```

I would expect to see in financial data a wide peak in because the influence of one market over other is gradual.

[image]